# What service should I use for changing coupon status in VCR and EMD?

Tags: sabre, vcr

I have vcr and EMD. All ones have coupon status OK. 
I need to change it on EXCH.
There is a commands 
VCRSTATUS/C1/TO-EXCH-REF TO MCO0010010111222
WEMDSTATUS/C1/TO-EXCH-REF TO MCO0010010111222
but it doesn't work in SabreCommand

```
     <ns:SabreCommandLLSRQ Version="1.6.1">
     <ns:Request Output="SCREEN" CDATA="true">
        <ns:HostCommand>VCRSTATUS/C1/TO-EXCH-REF TO MCO0010010111222</ns:HostCommand>
     </ns:Request>
  </ns:SabreCommandLLSRQ>

  <SabreCommandLLSRS>
     <Response>INVALID ENTRY</Response>
  </SabreCommandLLSRS>
```

Comment: Hi @Mikhail, welcome to stack overflow. Your question is not clear, could you add more details to it? This will increase the probability that someone will help you.

Answer (score 0):

There's one service called TicketingDocumentServicesRQ that should allow you to change the status to USED but no to EXCH:
https://developer.sabre.com/docs/sabre_sonic_apis/soap/ticketing/get_ticket_doc_details

There's no service to change the status to EXCH, because there's no purpose in everyday life, that is likely for testing. If the response is INVALID ENTRY, then you should reach out to SabreSonic support... assuming you are working for an airline.

If you are actually working for an agency, then you cannot change the status of the ticket.

The other option is for you to actually exchange the ticket:

- For airlines:

  - https://developer.sabre.com/docs/sabre_sonic_apis/soap/exchanges/auto_exchange_and_refund
- For agencies:

  - https://developer.sabre.com/docs/soap_apis/air/fulfill/Auto_Price_Air_Exchanges
  - https://developer.sabre.com/docs/soap_apis/air/fulfill/exchange_booking (this might work too)

For